# Is there a function to get a string out of an arrray via its index

Tags: javascript

I'm making a randomizer for a Tetris type game and was wondering how to use the index int (used pieceNum as the var for the index) to get the string out of the array Tetris.

Ps. This is my first post on stack overflow so please tell me if there's anything I can improve on when it comes to asking the questions

```
// Array for the tetriminos
var tetris = ['T', 'O', 'S', 'Z', 'J', 'L', 'I']

function piecePicker {
  var piecesLeft = 7;
  var pieceNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * piecesLeft)

  console.log(pieceNum)
  console.log()  <------needs to go here
  tetris.splice(pieceNum)
  piecesLeft -= 1;
}
```

Comment: use splice(pieceNum, 1)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `brackets` in order to use an element by its *index*.

Also, you should pass the second parameter to your `splice` index.

```js
var tetris = ['T', 'O', 'S', 'Z', 'J', 'L', 'I']

function piecePicker(){
  var piecesLeft = 7;
  var pieceNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * piecesLeft)

  console.log(pieceNum)
  console.log(tetris[pieceNum]);
  tetris.splice(pieceNum, 1)
  piecesLeft -= 1;
}

piecePicker();
console.log(tetris);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call the index directly on the array with the brackets `myArray[myIndex]`

```js
// Array for the tetriminos
var tetris = ['T', 'O', 'S', 'Z', 'J', 'L', 'I']

function piecePicker() {
  var piecesLeft = 7;
  var pieceNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * piecesLeft);

  console.log("Index", pieceNum);
  console.log("Letter", tetris[pieceNum]);
  tetris.splice(pieceNum);
  piecesLeft -= 1;
}

piecePicker();
```

*Note:* Take care that the variable `piecesLeft` will always be equal to 7 as it is declared inside the function

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! Modified the function to accept array as input and set the `piecesLeft` to be the length of the inputted array.

Assuming, you're trying to remove/pick one random value by calling `splice`, you'll need to input another param for the length, i.e. `arr.splice(randIndex, 1)`. 
`splice` will return back an array of the removed value and you can access this value by the index. As only 1 single value is removed the index will be `0`.

```js
// Array for the tetriminos
var tetris = ['T', 'O', 'S', 'Z', 'J', 'L', 'I']

function piecePicker(tetrisArr) {
  var piecesLeft = tetrisArr.length;
  var pieceNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * piecesLeft)

  // the removed index
  console.log('Removed index: ' + pieceNum);
  
  // pick the piece, and remove from the arr
  let spliced = tetrisArr.splice(pieceNum,1);
  // the removed val
  console.log('Removed value: ' + spliced[0]);    
  piecesLeft -= 1;
}

// call the function, randomly pick the value and remove it from the tetris arr
piecePicker(tetris);
```